# Finding the particular solution to the following non-homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

$$x_n = 2x_{n-1}+2^n$$
$$x_1 =5$$

Finding the homogenous solution is easy enough but when attempting to solve the particular solution I arrive at:

$$C_22^n = 2C_22^{n-1} + 2^n $$
$$2C_2 = 2C_2 + 2 $$
$$ 2=0$$

At this point, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: what is the boundary condition? I mean what is $x_0$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I added an edit to the original question. It's given that $x_1$ = 5.

Comment: I'm new to the formatting and I mistyped the problem. An edit has been made.

Comment: http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs504/s00m/notes/recurrence/solve/step2/step2.html This site seems to have a lot of good examples if you like the method of undermined coefficients. One of the examples suggest using $x_n=A \cdot n \cdot 2^{n}$ as the particular solution since the homogeneous solution already has $ \text{ some constant } \cdot 2^n$ in it.

Comment: @randomgirl Could you post that as an answer? I haven't dealt with summations when solving relations yet, and your way seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_n = 2x_{n-1}+2^n \\ x_n=An2^{n} \\ x_{n-1}=A(n-1)2^{n-1} \\ x_n=2x_{x-1}+2^n \text{ gives us } \\ A n 2^{n}=2A(n-1)2^{n-1}+2^n \\  An2^{n}=A(n-1)2^{n}+2^n \\ An=A(n-1)+1 \\ An=An-A+1 \\ -A+1=0 \\ A=1$

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_0=0$. From:
$$ x_n-2x_{n-1} = 2^n \tag{1} $$
it follows that:
$$ x_{n-1}-2x_{n-2} = 2^{n-1}, $$
$$ x_{n-2}-2x_{n-3} = 2^{n-2}, $$
$$ \ldots  \tag{2} $$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} x_n &=& (x_n-2x_{n-1})+2(x_{n-1}-2x_{n-2})+2^2(x_{n-2}-2x_{n-3})+\ldots\\ &=& \sum_{j=1}^{n}2^{j-1}(x_{n-j+1}-2 x_{n-j})=\sum_{j=1}^{n}2^{j}\cdot 2^{n-j+1}=n 2^{n+1}.\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
If $x_1=5$, the solution to $x_{n}=2 x_{n-1}+2^n $ is given by:
$$ x_n = 2^{n-1} + n 2^{n+1} = (1+4n)\, 2^{n-1}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Sorry, the last term should be $2^n$ not $2n^2$. I'm not used to the formatting and I mistyped the problem. An edit has been made.

Comment: @Eunkai: quite a substantial mistype!